# Invalid memory access in JNA

Tags: java, jna

When using JNA, I am receiving an Invalid Memory Access error when invoking the `QLConnect` method.

Here is my interface mapping the DLL:

```java
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

public interface QuikLimit extends StdCallLibrary {
    
    QuikLimit INSTANCE = (QuikLimit) Native.load(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\QuikLimit.dll", QuikLimit.class);
    
    int QLConnect(String userName, String userPassword, byte[] desc);
    
    //more methods from dll
}
```

I have another class with constants:

```java
public class Const {
    public static final int DESC_SIZE = 1024;
    
    public enum Status {
        //enum values

        int code;

        private Status(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }
        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }
    };
}
```

And here is the place of occurrence in the code:

```java
@Component
public class ConnectionManager {
    
    @Value("${quik.login}")
    private String login;
    @Value("${quik.password}")
    private String password;

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    private boolean connected;

    public synchronized BaseResponse connect() {
        BaseResponse result = new BaseResponse();
        byte[] desc = new byte[Const.DESC_SIZE]; 
        if (connected) {
        //logic if connected
        logger.info("call QLConnect");
        int retVal = QuikLimit.INSTANCE.QLConnect(login, password, desc);
        if (retVal == Const.Status.QL_ACTIVE.getCode()) {       
        //logic from response
        } else if (retVal == Const.Status.QL_CONNECTEDNOTACTIVE.getCode()) {
        //logic from response
        }
        result.setCode(retVal);
        result.setDescription(Util.descToStr(desc));
        QuikLimit.INSTANCE.QLDisconnect();
        return result;
    }
}
```

I understand that 1 assumption immediately falls on the fact that the type does not match in the dll. But the header file clearly states that the return type is int:

```c
typedef __int32             ql_long;
ql_long _stdcall QLConnect(const char* lpszUserName, const char* lpszUserPassword, char* lpszError);
```

lpszUserName is a pointer to an ASCIIZ string containing the username.

pszUserPassword is a pointer to an ASCIIZ string containing the user's
password.

lpszDesc is a pointer to a buffer into which, in case of an error, the
line with its description. The minimum buffer size is 512 bytes.

What else could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
[Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: There's not really enough information here for us to answer this question. "Invalid Memory Access" means you're using native memory that you don't "own".  While the return type is probably not the problem, it's not clear about the error message. Is 1024 enough bytes for it?  Where did the 1024 come from?

Comment: @Daniel Widdis thanks for the answer. I added the code in more detail. Unfortunately, I got the code from another developer with whom I have no connection. I can only say that on the test bench, this code works fine, but when the customer transferred it to the pre-production, this error occurred. 1024 I think it was chosen with a margin. can be seen above in the documentation for this api, the minimum size is 512

Comment: Try adding `W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS` or `ASCII_OPTIONS` as a third argument to your `Native.load()` call.

Comment: @Daniel Widdis thank you very much for your help, explicitly specifying the ascii encoding fixed this error

Comment: Great, I had that suspicion. I'll write that up in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to check when you get Invalid Memory Access errors is your type mapping, which you correctly started with looking at the `int` return value.  Turns out the `String` mapping for the other arguments, which works fine on *nix systems, needs a little special treatment on Windows.

By default Windows uses UTF 16 encoding, and JNA's default type mapping under-the-hood tries to convert Java `String` objects to UTF-16 encoded native strings (`wchar*`).  This works fine for Windows API DLLs.

However, your custom DLL specified that the User Name and Password arguments should be in ASCIIZ format (null-terminated C strings).

You can force JNA to use an ASCII `String` type mapper by including `W32APIOptions.ASCII_OPTIONS` as a third argument when loading the DLL, e.g.,

```java
QuikLimit INSTANCE = (QuikLimit) Native.load(new File("").getAbsolutePath() + "\\QuikLimit.dll", QuikLimit.class, W32APIOptions.ASCII_OPTIONS);
```

There are other finer grained approaches dealing just with String type mapping, that don't try to also do Function mapping (if any of your mapped functions end in W or A this might break!).  You can dig into the `W32APIOptions` class to see how to create your own custom options to pass.